# Getting out of newly applied inline style

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to apply inline styles to a selection made in CKEditor. The styles apply fine, but I can't get out of the style once I've applied it to the selection.

This is what I have:

```
var selection = editor.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRanges()[ 0 ];

// Apply style.
var style = new CKEDITOR.style( {
    element: 'a'
} );

style.type = CKEDITOR.STYLE_INLINE; // need to override... dunno why.
style.applyToRange( range, editor );
range.select();
```

So, I do that to the current selection. I then try to type after and the style keeps being applied, so I just keep appending to the link string.

I took the above code from the core Link plugin: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/link/dialogs/link.js

You can find it in the onOk function around line 804. Their link plugin works fine in terms of applying the style and being able to continue writing normally after. It's the continue writing normally part I'm stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem... You can't have an empty attributes object.

Fixed by doing this:

```
var style = new CKEDITOR.style( {
    element: 'a',
    attributes: {
        'href': 'www.test.com'
    }
} );
```